# How to get GPS Coordinates accurately and fast in all conditions (in village and cities)

Tags: android, gps

I am new to android , i am working with an application that captures  GPS in cities and village's , In cities my code is working fine , but in villages i am not getting .can any please sort a solution . what i need is I should get Exact GPS Coordinates (i.e. `GPS_PROVIDER` not Network Provider)

The code i have used:
When i click capture GPS button i am calling `gpsFinding()`

```
// gps code new

public void gpsFinding() {
    loc = null;
    turnGPSOn();
    progressBar = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressBar
            .setMessage("Please Wait!...Searching for GPS Coordinates...");
    progressBar.setCancelable(false);
    progressBar.setOnDismissListener(this);
    progressBar.show();
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    listener = new MyLocationListener();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,// network
                                                                        // provider,GPS_PROVIDER
            1000, 0, listener);
    startThread();

}

public void startThread() {
    cnt = 0;
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (cnt != 20) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    cnt++;
                    System.out.println("waiting...");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            progressBar.dismiss();
        }
    }.start();
}

private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            loc = location;
            gpsData = loc.getLatitude() + "-" + loc.getLongitude();

            double lati, longi;

            lati = loc.getLatitude();
            longi = loc.getLongitude();

            String displayGps = " Latitude : " + lati + " , Longitude : "
                    + longi;
            tv_ex_gps.setText(displayGps);

            Helper.GPS = gpsData.trim();

            btn_save.requestFocus();
            btn_save.requestFocusFromTouch();
            // tv_gpsLati.setText("Latitude : " +
            // displayGps.trim().split("\\,")[0]);
            // tv_gpsLongi.setText("Longitude : " +
            // displayGps.trim().split("\\,")[1]);

            // Toast.makeText(TrackAssetCode.this,
            // "Co-ordinates are received.", 5000).show();
            locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
            location = null;
            turnGPSOff();
            progressBar.dismiss();
        } else {
        }
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
}

private void turnGPSOn() {

    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
            Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
    if (!provider.contains("gps")) { // if gps is disabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings",
                "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
        sendBroadcast(poke);
    }
}

private void turnGPSOff() {
    System.out.println("We are in Off");
    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
            Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

    if (provider.contains("gps")) { // if gps is enabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings",
                "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
        sendBroadcast(poke);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    if (gpsData.length() == 0)
        showGPSAlert();
}

public void showGPSAlert() {
    b = new AlertDialog.Builder(Existing_Kiosk.this);
    b.setTitle("Message");
    b.setMessage("GPS Co-ordinates not received yet. Do you want wait some more time ?");
    b.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
    b.setCancelable(false);
    b.setPositiveButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            progressBar = new ProgressDialog(Existing_Kiosk.this);
            progressBar
                    .setMessage("Please Wait!...Searching for GPS Coordinates...");
            progressBar.setCancelable(false);
            progressBar.setOnDismissListener(Existing_Kiosk.this);
            progressBar.show();
            startThread();
        }
    });
    b.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            turnGPSOff();
            // btn_traastCod_gps.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });
    b.show();

}
```

Comment: as GPS PROVIDER works with a coordination with the settalite so i do not think it is a problem with city v/s village, it may be possible that the device was in a good area to fetch GPS as it depends on constraints like building etc

Answer (score 1):

GPS (or more exactly GNSS) is the only system that gives precise positions. So your approach to exclusivley use the GPS-Provider is correct.

But:
You need free view to sky.  
It does therfore not work indoors.  
It works bad in woods.
Having free view to sky expect to have to wait 20 - 40 s for the first valid location.
It urban canyons with bad view to sky, it may took much longer for the first valid coordinate. But you can do nothing, you cannot improve that. (you might wait to have a location before entering a vehicle).
In your app consider to display when having good GPS, such that the user has a feedback.

Your code should not limit to 20s, rearange your code that you dont wait for GPS, instead switch a state to haveGPS=true once receiving a valid location.

Answer (score 0):

As a guess, are you connected to a data network when in the village?  GNSS receivers get assistance from the network that can make the work much faster.  It may also work if you are connected to WiFi but it depends on the mobile device.  You can know if you are connected to a data network if you can use a browser to surf the web successfully.